# Error al ejecutar pod install en proyecto flutter

Tags: flutter, ios, firebase-auth, firebase-messaging, cocoapods

Estoy presentando el siguiente error al ejecutar `pod install` en proyecto.

El proyecto estaba funcionando bien hasta que actualice version de flutter y a la vez varias dependencias.

¿Alguien me podria ayudar con este error?

> firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '10.10.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
> firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '10.10.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
> firebase_messaging: Using Firebase SDK version '10.10.0' defined in 'firebase_core'

Comment: Puede que esto te sea de ayuda: [firebase_auth, etc, version conflict with Firebase SDK 10.0.0](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9792).

Answer (score -1):

Según tengo entendido, los pods se quedan almacenados en caché y cuando los reinstalas, a veces no descarga la última versión, sino la que esté cacheada, lo que puede provocar errores con Flutter en la parte de IOS. La solución que me suele funcionar es eliminar los pod directamente.

Puedes seguir los siguientes pasos:

Ve a tu proyecto Flutter y localiza la carpeta `ios`, en ella están contenidos los ficheros de configuración nativa para dicho sistema operativo.

Localiza después el fichero pods.lock y la carpeta pods. Borra ambos. Puedes borrarlo desde cmd o desde el propio IDE, no hay diferencia. Es decir, bórralos como quieras.

Después abre una terminal y navega hasta la carpeta `ios` de ese proyecto Flutter. Por último, ejecuta el siguiente comando desde la terminal, dentro de la carpeta `ios`: `pod install --repo-update`. Este comando reinstalará los pods.